# Change state with link in Streamlit DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, streamlit

Is there a way to change a state with a column link in Streamlit or a DataFrame in general?

I've been using `LinkColumn` in Streamlit in order to change the state.  For example, in the image below, I'd like to click on the Symbol and the bottom graph (which is called `show_company_info("CXAI")`).  For now an input text bar takes the place of searching for the stock but ideally I'd click on the DataFrame row and call the function.

I tried using State in Streamlit but the link in the column is cannot alter the Streamlit state.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: do you want to have the input text bar populated by the cell that you click on under the `Symbol` column, or would you prefer to have the button greyed out until you click on an entry under the `Symbol` column?

Comment: @DerekO The latter.  There would be no search bar and button and instead the "CXApp..." would be populated since the input of the function rendering would have the input that the search bar currently inputs.